# Auto populate field(s) based on text value Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to auto populate fields E3:E99, F3:F99, and G3:G99 based on the text value of fields B3:B99. So when Sam's is inserted anywhere between B3:B99 fields automagically populate with preassigned data. In my case:
E3:E99 will always be 164
F3:F99 will always be 45
G3:G99 will always be 40

Currently am trying to use the following but to no success:
=$B$3:$B$99="Sam's" =$E$3:$E$99="164.00" =$F$3:$F$99="45.00" =$G$3:$G$99=40
and I have it placed in Q3 away from my table so users cannot see it.

What am I missing or not formatting correctly yo auto populate fields based on B3:B99?

I have tried googling as much as possible and have tried a few different appscript methods that did not work.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

So I think you will be able to use a simple IF statement logic check combined with an array formula. This is assuming that the values in column B are entered manually. This is the formula to enter into E3. It will automatically check all values in B and output the 124 value when B=Sam's while leaving the value null if it is not Sam's.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B$3:$B$99="Sam's",124,))
```

This is the formula for F3:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B$3:$B$99="Sam's",45,))
```

And the formula for G3:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B$3:$B$99="Sam's",40,))
```

Comment: It seems to want to work but it doesn't populate the field. If I go into conditional formatting and set custom value for E3:E99/$E$3:$E$99 to  =ArrayFormula(IF($B$3:$B$99="Sam's",124,)) it changes the field fill color but does not add in the 124 value.

Comment: @DennisAlexander what formatting type do you have for the cell/the entire column in E?

Comment: @DennisAlexander this also won't work as a conditional format. It would have to populate the value of the different columns (E, F, and G) by being a formula in the actual cells not as a conditional format.